# Can we say an atom is ferromagnetic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Some atoms have nonzero magnetic moments. Does it make sense to say they are ferromagnetic?

Or should we say it is paramagnetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ferromagnetism is a collective behavior so the answer to your 1st question is no. In a ferromagnetic material the moments of the magnetic atoms not only align themselves with an external magnetic field but they also align spontaneously in the same direction even without any external field. The regions in the material where the magnetic moments have the same direction when there is no external magnetic field are called "magnetic domains" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain). Under an external field the magnetic domains tend to align in the direction of the external field.

Paramagnetism also deals with a collective behavior of atoms/molecules so the answer to your second question is no either. The reason is that when there is no external magnetic field the magnetic atoms/molecules should have their magnetic moments pointing in random directions with respect to each other and so there is a necessity of having more than 1 atom if you want to call your material paramagnetic.

I don't know if there's a single word for "atom with non zero magnetic moment" which is, I think, what you are looking for.

Note that in my reply I used the term "magnetic atom/molecule" for that matter.